Dead Battery, Good Alternator
I have a 2016 Buick Encore SUV base. Have check the battery alternator all good. When the emergency light are on and nothing else is on battery is dead in 15 minutes need jump.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How old is the battery? When you say you checked the battery and it's good, what are you calling good?

Ray, a quick check says that your Encore takes a 650 CCA battery, so the way to test the battery is to start with a fully charged battery and put a steady load of 325 amps on the battery for 15 seconds and take a voltage reading while still under load just before ending the test. At that time the voltage under load should be more than 10 - 10.5 volts depending on ambient temperature. Was that how you tested the battery? If not, how did you test it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This was very helpful. The people at auto zone test battery when engine off and had us to start the car to test the alternator.

The battery is this year. The people at auto zone test the battery and say it was good. Than we started car to test the alternator and it was producing 12 volt. The only time there is a problem is when the emergency lights are flashing for about 14 minutes we have to jump start the car. Thank you

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
